# FFmpeg make mpeg2 ts without discontinuity

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I have many MOV files recorded with iPhone and I want to convert them to mpeg2 TS. I want to use them for live video streaming with HTTP Live Streaming protocol.

I set my iPhone to continiously send MOV files to server. Every video clip is 5 seconds long. I want to make mpeg2 TS out of them and add their urls to m3u8 playlist.
I managed to do all of that, but when I try to play the stream VLC player plays only first two files in playlist, and last file in playlist at that moment.
I searched the internet and I think this has something to do with discontinuity.

Is there any way to convert multiple MOV files into multiple mpeg2 TS segments without discontinuity?

Or maybe I'm doing something else wrong?
Here is my ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input,MOV -f mpegts output.ts
```

and here is my m3u8 list:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:EVENT
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:10,
fileSequence0.ts
#EXTINF:10,
fileSequence1.ts
#EXTINF:10,
fileSequence2.ts
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your series of movies is not a stream. When you create the individual mpeg2ts segments, the timestamps are re-set to 0 on each run of ffmpeg. You can try using the 
[setpts](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#setpts) filter to adjust the starting timestamp of each segment. But first you'll need to know the final pts of the previous segment.

Comment: I'm trying to do that but with no luck.
I tried to set #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY before every segment, but that makes no difference.

I get this message from VLC player:
    TS discontinuity (recieved 0, expected 8)

I examined my previous segment and last PTS was 446696, what is the ffmpeg command to properly adjust pts for next segment?

Comment: ^ An update on the proper command would be much appreciated as well. I'm able to get the ending pts for previous files, but not sure how to apply that to the next file.