# ffmpeg streaming multiple avi files as created

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, avi

Backstory:
I have a VB.net program (that is using a much older COM object accessing a DVR) to create sequentially numbered AVI files each 15 seconds in length. A new AVI is created every 15 seconds with the most recent 15 seconds of video in it. I know the exact datetime that correlates to each file. So files may be named (20121008-133445.avi, so yyyyMMdd-hhmmss.avi).

Question: Using ffmpeg/ffserver (preferably but I'm open), how can I create a stream such that when a person accesses it that they are presented a continuous video that starts at a position that is as recent as possible and continues to stream the avi files as they are created?

I don't have a problem shipping these files off to a Linux box via a samba share (or have the linux box access a share on the windows box) if Linux is more capable. I am however stuck with Windows for the actual generation of the original AVI files.

The ultimate goal is to be able to view these streams on an iPad, but that process seems pretty well documented elsewhere.

I found a question that reads similar to my needs but didn't seem to go anywhere: [FFmpeg make mpeg2 ts without discontinuity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825476/ffmpeg-make-mpeg2-ts-without-discontinuity)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write a small program that simply reads these files one after another continously and dumps them to a named pipe.  Ffmpeg can then read from the named pipe and it will think it is one file.

The more complex solution is to use multifilesrc from gstreamer.

Comment: I did, and got `[flv @ 0x55f04a294280] Packet mismatch -1243485737 5002764 19829709` error from `ffmpeg`.