# How to adjust mpeg 2 ts start time with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, mpeg2-ts, ffprobe

I'm writing simple HLS (Http Live Streaming) java server to live cast (really live, not on demand) screenshow + voice. I constantly get chunks of image frames and audio samples as input to my service and produce mpeg 2 ts files + m3u8 playlist web page as output. The workflow is the following:

1. Collect (buffer) source video frames and audio for certain period of time
2. Convert series of video frames to h.264 encoded video file
3. Convert audio samples to mp3 audio file
4. Merge them to `.ts` file with ffmpeg command

   ```
   ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -i video.mp4 -f mpegts -c:a copy -c:v copy -vprofile main -level:v 4.0 -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -flags -global_header segment.ts
   ```
5. Publish several `.ts` files on m3u8 playlist.

The problem is resulting playlist interrupts after first segment is played. VLC logs following error:

```
freetype error: Breaking unbreakable line
ts error: libdvbpsi (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 0, expected 4) for PID 17
ts error: libdvbpsi (PSI decoder): TS duplicate (received 0, expected 1) for PID 0
ts error: libdvbpsi (PSI decoder): TS duplicate (received 0, expected 1) for PID 4096
core error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR is called too late (pts_delay increased to 1000 ms)
core error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
core error: Could not convert timestamp 185529572000
ts error: libdvbpsi (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 0, expected 4) for PID 17
ts error: libdvbpsi (PSI decoder): TS duplicate (received 0, expected 1) for PID 0
ts error: libdvbpsi (PSI decoder): TS duplicate (received 0, expected 1) for PID 4096
core error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR is called too late (jitter of 8653 ms ignored)
core error: Could not get display date for timestamp 0
core error: Could not convert timestamp 185538017000
core error: Could not convert timestamp 185538267000
core error: Could not convert timestamp 185539295977
...
```

I guess the reason is that start time of segments do not belong to one stream, but it's impossible to concat and resegment (with `ffmepg -f segment`) whole stream once new chunk is added. Tried adding `#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY` tag to playlist as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825476/ffmpeg-make-mpeg2-ts-without-discontinuity) but it didn't help. When I `ffprobe` them I get:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from '26.ts':
Duration: 00:00:10.02, start: 1.876978, bitrate: 105 kb/s
Program 1
Metadata:
  service_name    : Service01
  service_provider: FFmpeg
Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 640x640, 4 fps, 4 tbr, 90k tbn, 8 tbc
Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, mono, s16p, 64 kb/s
```

Where start value in line `Duration: 00:00:10.02, start: 1.876978, bitrate: 105 kb/s` is more or less equal for all segments.
When I check segments from available proven-to-work playlists (like http://vevoplaylist-live.hls.adaptive.level3.net/vevo/ch1/appleman.m3u8) they all have diffrenet start values for each segment, for example:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'segm150518140104572-424570.ts':
Duration: 00:00:06.17, start: 65884.808689, bitrate: 479 kb/s
Program 257
Stream #0:0[0x20]: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 320x180 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
Stream #0:1[0x21]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 115 kb/s
Stream #0:2[0x22]: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
```

and the next after it

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'segm150518140104572-424571.ts':
Duration: 00:00:06.22, start: 65890.814689, bitrate: 468 kb/s
Program 257
Stream #0:0[0x20]: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 320x180 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
Stream #0:1[0x21]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 124 kb/s
Stream #0:2[0x22]: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
```

differ in the way that start time of `segm150518140104572-424571.ts` is equal to start time + duration of `segm150518140104572-424570.ts`.

How could this start value be adjusted with `ffmpeg`? Or maybe my whole aproach is wrong? Unfortunately I couldn't find on the internet working example of live (not on demand) video service implemented with ffmepg.

Comment: Can you share your 4 ts segments? you can send me links. I will use them in my playlist and see what is happening.

Comment: @Alam [Here are examples](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kt13acxo459oz3q/AACV-OD9RXT9JNh9PMPnAuWEa?dl=0)

Comment: Your segments 38.ts, 39.ts, 40.ts and 41.ts are all same files. (Check your buffer if they are getting updated)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've answered my own question with approach described [here](https://github.com/victusfate/mpegtsShifter).
Timestamp could be adjusted with `-initial_offset` parameter of `-f segment` format:

```
ffmpeg -i in.ts -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f segment -initial_offset 10 -segment_format mpegts out%d.ts
```

For each new segment I calculate necessary `-initial_offset` as sum of all previous segments length.

Comment: Did you use 2 `ffmpeg` commands to get to the ts files? Also when I tried your 2nd command with `-initial_offset 10` now I ended up start time to be 11.4s. Did you run into the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Its more than just timestamps, It is also continuity indicators. So setting the start time will not fix your problem. You must encode as a single stream.

Answer (score 0):

you can set "-segment_time 20"  to make ouput only one ts file

```
fmpeg.exe -i 0.mp3 -c copy -bsf:v aac_adtstoasc -f segment -segment_time 20 -initial_offset 10 -segment_format mpegts out%d.ts
```